# Class Not Found For MDSBackingStore in OCJ4

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, jndi, classnotfoundexception

I deploy an ear application in ocj4 server.
When i try to access the application, the exception is occured :

```
500 Internal Server Error

Servlet error: An exception occurred. The current application deployment descriptors do      not allow for including it in this response. Please consult the application log for details.
```

I open the application.log :

```
12/12/11 13:47:54.76 ViewArchive: Servlet error
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/adf/share/jndi/MDSBackingStore
    at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.loadFromClassPath(Configuration.java:446)
at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.PoolMgr.loadConfiguration(PoolMgr.java:600)
at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.PoolMgr.findPool(PoolMgr.java:526)
at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(Configuration.java:1513)
at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(Configuration.java:1490)
at LoginModule.view.utils.LoginValidateDB.checkUserExist(LoginValidateDB.java:24)
at LoginModule.view.utils.LoginValidateServlet.doPost(LoginValidateServlet.java:44)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:734)
at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:391)
at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:908)
at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:458)
at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:226)
at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:127)
at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:116)
at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.procClientSocket(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:234)
at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.access$700(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:29)
at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler$AcceptHandlerHorse.run(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:879)
at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:298)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
 Caused by: oracle.classloader.util.AnnotatedClassNotFoundException: 

  Missing class: oracle.adf.share.jndi.MDSBackingStore

Dependent class: oracle.jbo.client.Configuration
         Loader: JAS.web.ViewArchive:0.0.0
    Code-Source: /C:/Users/iswanto/Desktop/oc4j_extended_101350/j2ee/home/applications/JAS/ViewArchive/WEB-INF/lib/adfm.jar
```

I try to search JAR files that contain MDSBackingStore but not found.
The question is : how can i get that jar ?

Thanks.